# Remove last child page from URI

Tags: php, wordpress, url, path, uri

How can one dynamically find and remove the last child of a website path URI?

Code: `$uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];`

Result: http://192.168.0.16/wordpress/blog/page-2/

Desired result: http://192.168.0.16/wordpress/blog/

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: But then will just blog resolve to page 2? also being pedantic last child would be `http://192.168.0.16/wordpress/blog/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this and you can get your required output:

```
// implode string into array
$url = "http://192.168.0.16/wordpress/blog/page-2/";
//then remove character from right
$url = rtrim($url, '/');
// then explode
$url = explode('/', $url);
// remove the last element and return an array
json_encode(array_pop($url));
// implode again into string
echo implode('/', $url);
```

another approach is:

```
// implode string into array
$url = explode('/', 'http://192.168.0.16/wordpress/blog/page-2/');
//The array_filter() function filters the values of an array using a callback function.
$url = array_filter($url);
// remove the last element and return an array
array_pop($url);
// implode again into string
echo implode('/', $url);
```

Comment: you can add this $url = array_filter($url);

Comment: Your first approach will not work. You have to trim the string, not array

Comment: Thanks to identify, that was mistakenly written. @Ravinder Reddy

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'http://192.168.0.16/wordpress/blog/page-2/';
  // trim any slashes at the end
  $trim_url = rtrim($url,'/');
  // explode with slash
  $url_array = explode('/', $trim_url);
  // remove last element
  array_pop($url_array);
  // implade with slash
  echo $new_url = implode('/', $url_array);
```

Output:

```
http://192.168.0.16/wordpress/blog
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way would be to use [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [dirname()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php), which will also support query params. You could explode `$uri['path']` but its unnecessary in this case.

```
<?php
// explode the uri in its proper parts
$uri = parse_url('/wordpress/blog/page-2/?id=bla');

// remove last element
$path = dirname($uri['path']);

// incase you got query params, append them
if (!empty($uri['query'])) {
    $path .= '?'.$uri['query'];
}

// string(22) "/wordpress/blog?id=bla"
var_dump($path);
```

**See it working:** https://3v4l.org/joJrF